# Stored Procedure Not Inserting Any Data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I wrote following stored procedure to insert list of batch of data.  The stored procedure compiles successfully but does not insert any entry.  I am very new to stored procedure do not know what am I am i missing.  Can anyone please comment:

Here we are trying to add List of URL and pe_tier into the database

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `KKEventsInBulk`(
IN url varchar(4096),
IN emailArchivePath varchar (4096),
IN orgId int,
IN feedId int,
IN normalized_pattern_string varchar (4096),
IN uuid varchar(4096),
IN pe_tier int)
BEGIN
DECLARE p2 varchar(4000);
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
       BEGIN
             ROLLBACK;
              GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
              p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
              SET p2=concat('Error ',p2);
            SELECT p2;
        END;
        INSERT INTO kk_pattern (uuid, nomalized_pattern_string) values(uuid, normalized_pattern_string);
    WHILE url != '' DO
       IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM url_event_detail ue where ue.url=url) THEN
                 INSERT INTO kk_event_detail(eventID,email_archive_path, patternID) values((select event_id from url_event_detail), email_archive_path, 
                 (select id from pe_pattern p where p.normalized_pattern_string=normalized_pattern_string));
       ELSE 
          BEGIN
                INSERT INTO kk_waiting_on_ce(url, pe_tier, email_archive_path, pattern_id, org_id, feed_id)values
                (url, pe_tier, email_archive_path, 
                 (select id from pe_pattern p where p.normalized_pattern_string = normalized_pattern_string and p.uuid=uuid ),
                 org_id, feed_id);
        END;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: That syntax is not sql-server...

Comment: I am running this on mysql.  And it compiles successfully.

Comment: Thanks bastos.sergio can you please elaborate what syntax am i missing here?